# content replace js script fails

Tags: javascript, replace

The code below does not appear to function properly.  newH2Text should replace para1.  This does not happen.  I used Sublime, then looked through the browser console, and even on SO's code snippet.  I am almost certain I have the code verbatim.

The first paragraph, which has its own id attribute should be replaced by newH2Text which is created in my JS script.  I can't find my mistake here.   Please help.

PS the refresh button works properly. No issue there.

```js
function replaceHeading(){
  var newH2=document.createElement("h2");
  var newH2Text=document.createTextNode("Welcome");
  newH2.appendChild(newH2Text);
  var myDiv=document.getElementById("id1");
  var oldP=document.getElementById("para1");
  myDiv.replaceChild(NewH2,oldP);
 }
window.onload=function() {
 document.getElementById("btn").onclick=replaceHeading;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
<p id="para1">Welcome to my web page.</p>
<p id="para2">Take a look around.</p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Replace Element">
<br>
<input type="button" value="refresh" onclick="location.reload()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NewH2` is capitalized but should be `newH2` with a lowercase.

```
myDiv.replaceChild(newH2,oldP);
```

See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5wn08j1/)** for an example

**Update**

To catch these errors earlier you can use "*strict mode*". An example of this would be:

```
;(function(){
   "use strict";
   function replaceHeading(){
          var newH2=document.createElement("h2");
          var newH2Text=document.createTextNode("Welcome");
          newH2.appendChild(newH2Text);
          var myDiv=document.getElementById("id1");
          var oldP=document.getElementById("para1");
          myDiv.replaceChild(NewH2,oldP);
     }
}());
```

Which would give you the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: NewH2 is not defined`.

Comment: That did the trick! Is there anyway to check for case? JS is case-sensitive but I looked through 3 different UIs and couldn't catch it.  Any suggestions?  By JS convention you always start with a lowercase.  But is there another precaution that I can take?

Comment: You can use "strict mode" in order to avoid this in the future. Then you will get an error in this situation. Check this for the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode . I actually also made a blog post about this a few weeks ago: https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2016/01/26/javascript-why-you-should-use-strict-and-what-it-is/ . I updated my answer to contain an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two different ways todo what you are trying:

```js
function replaceHeading(){
        /*****  CORRECTED AND WORKING
  var newH2=document.createElement("h2");
  var newH2Text=document.createTextNode("Welcome");
  newH2.appendChild(newH2Text);
  var oldP=document.getElementById("para1");
  document.getElementById("id1").replaceChild(newH2,oldP);
        *////
        // OR a more simpler way
        document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "<h2>Welcome</h2>";
 }
window.onload=function() {
 document.getElementById("btn").onclick=replaceHeading;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
<p id="para1">Welcome to my web page.</p>
<p id="para2">Take a look around.</p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Replace Element">
<br>
<input type="button" value="refresh" onclick="location.reload()">
</div>
```

Comment: I know via INNERhtml  but this is for a tutorial.  The point here is to get familiar with creating nodes and all that.  But yes innerhtml is simpler.  Also why would I need window.onload to use innerhtml ?

Comment: You need window.onload because you must be sure the document is full loaded so your document.getElementById("btn") can returns a valid value. An alternative to window.onload is to put all your javascript at the end of the document, immediately before the closing body tag "</body>;"